# Laravel 5.7 - How to set all variables inside .env to point to test environment when the system is started?

Tags: laravel-5, environment-variables, development-environment

I have 2 buckets prod and dev.
Inside .env I have S3_PROD and S3_DEV.
I want my system to point to S3_DEV when I am in my dev environment.

Taking consideration that I could have 10 variables to be pointed to a specific endpoint based on our environment what should be the best approach
to set that?

Answer (score 0):

You're .env file should not be tracked by whatever deployment/versioning system you have. Ideally your dev environment file would contain the keys appropriate and in your config you would simply call `env('S3_REGION')` for example.

But for the sake of bad ideas lets say you have almost identical .env files in your dev environment and your production, change the `APP_ENV=local` to dev or prod and then an `if` statement in your config.

I would highly recommend you follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration) on this.

> Your .env file should not be committed to your application's source
>   control, since each developer / server using your application could
>   require a different environment configuration. Furthermore, this would
>   be a security risk in the event an intruder gains access to your
>   source control repository, since any sensitive credentials would get
>   exposed.
>
> If you are developing with a team, you may wish to continue including
>   a .env.example file with your application. By putting placeholder
>   values in the example configuration file, other developers on your
>   team can clearly see which environment variables are needed to run
>   your application. You may also create a .env.testing file. This file
>   will override the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing
>   Artisan commands with the --env=testing option.